# Including SphinxAPI.php in PHP

Tags: php, windows, debian, sphinx

I've Sphinx installed on my VPS which has Debian 7 and also I have remote access to it from my PC which has Windows 8.

So now I have two webserver environments ( VPS with Debian and PC with Win8). Both of them have Sphinx PECL extension installed.
In general, all works fine, but there is one difference between my them in terms of using Sphinx.

When I run simple PHP script like:

```
<?php
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->setServer("1.2.3.4", 1234);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
$s->setMaxQueryTime(3);

$result = $s->query("Hello StackOverflow!");
var_dump($result);
```

On Windows it works fine. But on Debian it says that there is no `SphinxClient` class.
This is of course because I should `require`/`include` `sphinxapi.php` file. If I do so, it works fine on Debian too.

The question is, why this file is not needed on Windows and is required on Debian? 
I guess it's built in in Windows's PECL extension or something. But why there's such a difference?

Is there any rule for PECL extensions on Linux vs Windows OS?

Comment: Ok, but on Windows I just don't have this file. Sphinx extension for Windows was just a .dll file which I put into php/ext/ directory and enabled it in php.ini.

Comment: I'm also confused because some of Sphinx examples on the web says about including this file and some of them are not.

Comment: @dragoste, check your `php.ini`. Some files can be set up to be automatically included.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski As I wrote before "Sphinx extension for Windows was just a .dll file which I put into php/ext/ directory and enabled it in php.ini.". So there's nothing to be included.